# My controls in are not available to be used in a c# file in my project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Hi guys i have annoying problem with creating a reference from cs file to xaml file.**

solution explorer

[image: 1]

In AddModel.cs i want to do some validation and some extra things with specific control in this case is textbox. Here is a code in AddView.xaml

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <!--StandardLayout-->
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                            Value="{StaticResource LSize}" />

                        <Style.Triggers>

                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Converter={x:Static local:IsGreaterThanConverter.Instance}, ConverterParameter=1100}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                    Value="{StaticResource MSize}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
```

As you can see i included datatriggers which changing view depending on the width. Every of this views are defined below (this is a AddViewTemplate.xaml)

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LSize">        

        <Grid>
         
                <ContentControl Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Template="{StaticResource Brand}"/>
                <ContentControl Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Template="{StaticResource Model}"/>
                <ContentControl Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    Template="{StaticResource RegPlate}"/>
                <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Template="{StaticResource Position}"/>
                <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Template="{StaticResource Partner}"/>
                <ContentControl Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    Template="{StaticResource CC}"/>
                <ContentControl Grid.Column="2"
                                    Grid.Row="0"    
                                    Template="{StaticResource Cost}"/>
                <ContentControl Grid.Column="2"
                                    Grid.Row="1"    
                                    Template="{StaticResource Mileage}"/>
            </Grid>

    </DataTemplate>
```

this is only LSize template. There is some contentcontrols with all controls i have in this view. For the example this is code for Brand:

```
<ResourceDictionary>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Brand">
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource tGrid}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource Border1}"/>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource Border2}">
                <TextBox x:Name="BrandTextbox" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource txtBox}" Text="{Binding Brand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{Binding AddModel}"/>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Brand" Style="{StaticResource tBlock}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

i defined there a name - BrandTextbox. And now is a question how i supposed to reference to this textbox in AddModel.cs to do some things with it for example changing height or just validating inputed text values?

CMS - is name of my project

I cant write in AddModel.cs something like using CMS.Theme.Viewdata; because VS doesnt even propose me this to write. When i put empty cs file in this project then i can write using which i written before but this didnt help; still i cant reference to BrandTextbox. Im beginner in C# WPF things so dont judge me haha :D

thx for any help guys

Comment: "Brand" is a template. There is no `TextBox` to be referenced until the template has actually been applied to some control at runtime. When do you need the reference to the `TextBox`?

Comment: Basically, this is a way to get a list of labelled editable controls?  If you want to get at the textbox then you're probably best not putting it inside something re-usable in quite that way. Take a look at editrow here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29777.wpf-property-list-editing.aspx  Notice how you put whatever control you like inside the editrow and could set it's name, height or whatever. And use a control other than textbox if it suited - eg datepicker or combobox